# Can I rake the routes for a specific resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

I've been grepping the output of `rake routes` forever and it just dawned on me that someone must know a better way to inspect routes. I have a resource in my `routes.rb` name `account_groups`:

```
resources :account_groups
```

Is there anyway to tell `rake routes` to only return the routes associated with this resource?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with grep :p, works wonders

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can check for routes of specific controller:
`rake routes CONTROLLER=account_groups`

As seen in @ZiiCEagle's answer this is deprecated now and you should use
`rails routes -c account_groups`

Comment: Accept namespace: `rails routes -c admin/users`

Comment: There's also a grep option `rails routes -g something`

Answer (score 24):

I usually do `rake routes | grep ressource_name`.

Also check out [Rails HtmlRoutes](http://github.com/pierre-pretorius/html_routes) if you want it nice and pretty in HTML.

Answer (score 14):

```
rake routes CONTROLLER=controller_name
```

has been deprecated in rails 5.1.
Now it's

```
 rails routes -c controller_name
```

Answer (score 4):

For a namespaced controller:

```
CONTROLLER=admin/users rake routes
CONTROLLER=admin/user_sessions rake routes
```

Comment: Now `rails routes -c admin/users`